# Can't understand how the submit button is vertically aligned

Tags: javascript, html, css

When all the controls on this page are lined up, for some reason the submit button (and the first select control) are vertically aligned to the top of the other controls, even though the other controls HAVE a label and the submit DOESN'T...

Also if you resize the page so that the controls are broken over two lines, the submit button align to the top and not to the other controls anymore.

http://test.cdudigital.com/?q=test

Why is this?

Comment: Please update your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40981776/cannot-figure-out-how-this-button-is-vertically-aligned) with a [mcve] -- don't repost the same question multiple times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the vertical-align property is not set on the button, there is no consistent reference from which to position the button. If you set the vertical-align property to "top" and give the button a margin-top of 1 em (this being the presumed size of the labels above the other elements), it will position itself consistently.

```
<input name="test6" class="form-submit" id="edit-test6" style="vertical-align: top;margin-top:1em;" type="submit" value="Apply">
```

Comment: If that's the case the button still has baseline set when it breaks over 2 lines, but it suddenly aligns to the top...?

Comment: Wow, you are correct. That is still odd, but I see how to resolve. I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apply button doesn't have `vertical-align: top` property.